# network device command parsing with pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, pyparsing, command-line-arguments

I`m developing network device command parser using pyparsing.

I analysed and define the command format as below:

```
cli ::= string + (next)*
next ::= string|range|group|simple_recursive|selective_recursive|infinite_recursive|keywords
keywords ::= "WORD"
             | "LINE" 
             | "A.B.C.D" 
             | "A.B.C.D/M" 
             | "X:X::X:X" 
             | "X:X::X:X/M" 
             | "HH:MM:SS" 
             | "AA:NN" 
             | "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" 
             | "MULTILINE"
inner_recur ::= next + (next)* + ("|")* | ("|" + next + (next)*)*
string ::= alphanums + "_" + "-"
range ::= "<" + nums + "-" nums + ">"
group ::= "(" + inner_recur + ")"
simple_recursive ::= "." + range
selective_recursive ::= "{" + inner_recur + "}"
infinite_recursive ::= "[" + inner_recur + "]"
```

and implemented written:

```
# string ::= alphanums + "_" + "-"
string_ = Word(alphanums + "_" + "-").setResultsName("string")
#print(string_.parseString("option82"))

# range ::= "<" + nums + "-" nums + ">"
range_ = Combine(Literal("<") + Word(nums) + Literal("-") + Word(nums) + Literal(">")).setResultsName("range")
#print(range_.parseString("<24-1004>"))

# simple_recursive ::= "." + range
simple_recursive_ = Combine(Literal(".") + range_).setResultsName("simple_recursive")
#print(simple_recursive_.parseString(".<1-60045>"))

# keywords ::= "WORD" | "LINE" | "A.B.C.D" | "A.B.C.D/M" | "X:X::X:X" | "X:X::X:X/M" | "HH:MM:SS" | "AA:NN" | "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" | "MULTILINE"
keywords_ = Keyword("X:X::X:X/M").setResultsName("X:X::X:/M") | Keyword("A.B.C.D/M").setResultsName("A.B.C.D/M") | Keyword("A.B.C.D").setResultsName("A.B.C.D") | Keyword("X:X::X:X").setResultsName("X:X::X:X") | Keyword("HH:MM:SS").setResultsName("HH:MM:SS") | Keyword("AA:NN").setResultsName("AA:NN") | Keyword("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX").setResultsName("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX") | Keyword("MULTILINE").setResultsName("MULTILINE") | Keyword("WORD").setResultsName("WORD") | Keyword("LINE").setResultsName("LINE")
#print(keywords_.parseString("A.B.C.D").asXML())


#next_ = Forward()
inner_recur = Forward()

# group ::= "(" + inner_recur + ")"
group_ = Combine(Literal("(") + inner_recur + Literal(")"))

# selective_recursive ::= "{" + inner_recur + "}"
selective_recursive_ = Combine(Literal("{") + inner_recur + Literal("}"))

# infinite_recursive ::= "[" + inner_recur + "]"
infinite_recursive_ = Combine(Literal("[") + inner_recur + Literal("]"))

# next ::= string|range|group|simple_recursive|selective_recursive|infinite_recursive|keywords
next_ = keywords_ | string_ | simple_recursive_ | range_ | group_ | selective_recursive_ | infinite_recursive_

# inner_recur ::= next + (next)* + ("|")* | ("|" + next + (next)*)*
inner_recur << next_ + ZeroOrMore(next_) + ZeroOrMore(Literal("|") | ZeroOrMore(Literal("|") + next_ + OneOrMore(next_)))

# cli ::= string + (next)*
cli_ = string_ + ZeroOrMore(next_)
```

To test my parser, I tried to input datas

```
>>> test = cli_.parseString("bgp as .<1-200>")
>>> print(test)
>>> ['bgp', 'as', ['.<1-200>']]
test = cli_.parseString("bgp as <1-200> <1-255> <1-255> WORD A.B.C.D A.B.C.D/M (A|(B|C))")
print(test)
>>> 
test = cli_.parseString("test (A|<1-200>|(B|{a|b|c} aaa)")
test = cli_.parseString("test (A|<1-200>|(B|{a|b|c|})|)")
```

when parsed second data, infinite recursion raised. I don't understand this situation and have any solution...

I expect the result:

> ['bgp', 'as', ['<1-200>'], ['<1-255>'], ['<1-255>'], 'WORD',
>   'A.B.C.D', 'A.B.C.D/M', ['A', ['B', 'C']]]

what is my problem in format or code? and point be modified?

Comment: Tried debugger with step-by-step execution?

Comment: Stepping through pyparsing with the debugger is pretty rough, even if you are familiar with the internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you have made a good first step in defining your grammar in conceptual BNF terms before writing code, I'm struggling a bit with making sense of your grammar. The culprit to me seems to be this part:

```
inner_recur ::= next + (next)* + ("|")* | ("|" + next + (next)*)*
```

From your posted examples, this looks like you are trying to define some sort of infix notation, using '|' as an operator.

From your tests, it also looks like you need to support multiple `inner_recur` terms within any grouping ()'s, []'s, or {}'s.

Also, please read the docs (https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html) to get a clearer picture of the difference between `setResultsName` and `setName`. I'm pretty sure in your parser throughout, you are using `setResultsName` but really want `setName`. Similarly with using `Combine` when you really want `Group`.

Lastly, I rewrote your test code using runTests, and saw that you had mismatched ()'s on the third test.

Here is your parser with these changes:

```
# string ::= alphanums + "_" + "-"
string_ = Word(alphanums + "_" + "-").setResultsName("string")
#print(string_.parseString("option82"))

# range ::= "<" + nums + "-" nums + ">"
range_ = Group(Literal("<") + Word(nums) + Literal("-") + Word(nums) + Literal(">")).setResultsName("range")
#print(range_.parseString("<24-1004>"))

# simple_recursive ::= "." + range
simple_recursive_ = Group(Literal(".") + range_).setResultsName("simple_recursive")
#print(simple_recursive_.parseString(".<1-60045>"))

# keywords ::= "WORD" | "LINE" | "A.B.C.D" | "A.B.C.D/M" | "X:X::X:X" | "X:X::X:X/M" | "HH:MM:SS" | "AA:NN" | "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" | "MULTILINE"
keywords_ = Keyword("X:X::X:X/M").setResultsName("X:X::X:/M") | Keyword("A.B.C.D/M").setResultsName("A.B.C.D/M") | Keyword("A.B.C.D").setResultsName("A.B.C.D") | Keyword("X:X::X:X").setResultsName("X:X::X:X") | Keyword("HH:MM:SS").setResultsName("HH:MM:SS") | Keyword("AA:NN").setResultsName("AA:NN") | Keyword("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX").setResultsName("XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX") | Keyword("MULTILINE").setResultsName("MULTILINE") | Keyword("WORD").setResultsName("WORD") | Keyword("LINE").setResultsName("LINE")
#print(keywords_.parseString("A.B.C.D").asXML())

#next_ = Forward()
inner_recur = Forward()

# group ::= "(" + inner_recur + ")"
group_ = Group(Literal("(") + OneOrMore(inner_recur) + Literal(")"))

# selective_recursive ::= "{" + inner_recur + "}"
selective_recursive_ = Group(Literal("{") + OneOrMore(inner_recur) + Literal("}"))

# infinite_recursive ::= "[" + inner_recur + "]"
infinite_recursive_ = Group(Literal("[") + OneOrMore(inner_recur) + Literal("]"))

# next ::= string|range|group|simple_recursive|selective_recursive|infinite_recursive|keywords
next_ = keywords_ | string_ | simple_recursive_ | range_ | group_ | selective_recursive_ | infinite_recursive_
#~ next_.setName("next_").setDebug()

# inner_recur ::= next + (next)* + ("|")* | ("|" + next + (next)*)*
#~ inner_recur <<= OneOrMore(next_) + ZeroOrMore(Literal("|")) | ZeroOrMore(Literal("|") + OneOrMore(next_))
inner_recur <<= Group(infixNotation(next_,
    [
        (None, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        ('|', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ]) + Optional('|'))
# cli ::= string + (next)*
cli_ = string_ + ZeroOrMore(next_)


tests = """\
bgp as .<1-200>
bgp as <1-200> <1-255> <1-255> WORD A.B.C.D A.B.C.D/M (A|(B|C))
test (A|<1-200>|(B|{a|b|c} aaa))
test (A|<1-200>|(B|{a|b|c|})|)
"""
cli_.runTests(tests)
```

Which gives:

```
bgp as .<1-200>
['bgp', 'as', ['.', ['<', '1', '-', '200', '>']]]
- simple_recursive: ['.', ['<', '1', '-', '200', '>']]
  - range: ['<', '1', '-', '200', '>']
- string: 'as'


bgp as <1-200> <1-255> <1-255> WORD A.B.C.D A.B.C.D/M (A|(B|C))
['bgp', 'as', ['<', '1', '-', '200', '>'], ['<', '1', '-', '255', '>'], ['<', '1', '-', '255', '>'], 'WORD', 'A.B.C.D', 'A.B.C.D/M', ['(', [['A', '|', ['(', [['B', '|', 'C']], ')']]], ')']]
- A.B.C.D: 'A.B.C.D'
- A.B.C.D/M: 'A.B.C.D/M'
- WORD: 'WORD'
- range: ['<', '1', '-', '255', '>']
- string: 'as'


test (A|<1-200>|(B|{a|b|c} aaa))
['test', ['(', [['A', '|', ['<', '1', '-', '200', '>'], '|', ['(', [['B', '|', [['{', [['a', '|', 'b', '|', 'c']], '}'], 'aaa']]], ')']]], ')']]
- string: 'test'


test (A|<1-200>|(B|{a|b|c|})|)
['test', ['(', [['A', '|', ['<', '1', '-', '200', '>'], '|', ['(', [['B', '|', ['{', [['a', '|', 'b', '|', 'c'], '|'], '}']]], ')']], '|'], ')']]
- string: 'test'
```

This may be off the mark in some places, but I hope it gives you some ideas to move forward with your project.

Comment: super thank you @PaulMcG! you make my day! That is working, so I can move next step. I'm going to read the docs and review the codes. Thanks for your detailed answer.